# Adding a dictionary item that is a dictionary itself

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider following dictionary:

```
dict1 = {"A":{"B":"C"}}
print(dict1["A"]["B"])
```

This prints 'C'

I can now modify my dictionary like this

```
dict1["A"]["B"] = "D"
dict1["A"]["E"] = "F"
dict1["B"] = "G"
print(dict1)
```

And the output is

```
{'A': {'B': 'D', 'E': 'F'}, 'B': 'G'}
```

but I can't do this:

```
dict1["C"]["H"] = ["I"]
```

this however works:

```
dict2 = {"H":"I"}
dict1["C"] = dict2
print(dict1)
```

Output:

```
{'A': {'B': 'D', 'E': 'F'}, 'B': 'G', 'C': {'H': 'I'}}
```

Is there an alternative that doesn't require creating an additional dictionary?

I am just playing around to learn the language and not working on a concrete project.
Still, any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can use `defaultdict`.

Comment: Or `dict1.setdefault("C", {})["H"] = "I"`

Comment: "I am just playing around to learn the language and not working on a concrete project. Still, any help would be appreciated" that's fine too! ;)

Comment: Thank you all for explaining it to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't created the dictionary `C` yet. In python you must first create it before editing it. Like this:

```
dict1 = {}
dict1["C"] = {} # First create it before modifying it
dict1["C"]["H"] = ["I"]
print(dict1)
```

Let me explain.

```
foomain["C"] = 'blah'
```

sets it, but

```
foomain['C']['H'] = 'blah'
```

attempts to find `foomain['C']`, and fails. If it worked, it would then take that dictionary and use the assignment operator on it to assign `blah` to `['C']['H']`.

It's like saying:

```
Okay, go find `foomain['C']`, then assign 'blah' to key 'H'
```

Instead of:

```
Okay, assign 'blah' to `foomain['C']['H']`
```

In other words, assignment and getting are entirely different in python.

Answer (score 3):

Why would dict1["C"]["H"] = ["I"] work if there is no element "C" in dict1?
Do this:

```
dict1["C"] = {}
dict1["C"]["H"] = ["I"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1["C"]["H"] = ["I"]
```

In the above, the problem is that `dict1["C"]` has not been initialized, and so it is not known whether it is a dict and can be assigned a sub-element like `["H"]` (or whether it is just, say, an integer and assigning to `["H"]` would be an error).

There are [packages to enable what you're talking about](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nested_dict), and using a defaultdict would work for a single level of nestedness.  But especially if you are starting out, it's probably better that you deal with such things explicitly.

```
val = dict1.get("C")
if isinstance(val, dict)
    dict1["C"]["H"] = "I"
else
    dict["C"] = {"H": "I"}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a one-liner tree in https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250. It was posted as a cute hack, but works reasonably well.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def tree(): return defaultdict(tree)

users = tree()
users['harold']['username'] = 'hrldcpr'
users['handler']['username'] = 'matthandlersux'
```

Because of the `defaultdict`, each access on an undefined key generates a new value, and because of the recursion the new value will also be a new tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setdefault which would assign default value in case of key error.

```
dict1.setdefault('C', {})['H'] = 'I'
```

Or you can altogether use defaultdict instead of dict.

```
from collections import defaultdict
```